# Values of $a$ that satisfy inequality

Tags: inequality

> Find the values of $a$ for which $9^{x+1}+(a^2-4a-2)\cdot3^x+1>0,$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

This is how I did it:
Since $9^{x+1}+1 > 0\text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R, (a^2-4a-2)3^x \text{ should be greater than } 0$, so
$$(a^2-4a-2)3^x>0\implies (a^2-4a-2)>0$$
$$\implies a\in[-\infty,2-\sqrt6]\cup[2+\sqrt6,\infty]$$
However, the correct answer is $a\in\mathbb R-\{2\}$.
What did I do wrong?
P.S. Although I have asked this question before, but now I want to know what's wrong in my new solution. So I don't need some other solution.

Comment: What you've done is the sufficiency, not necessity. For example $$Ax^2+Bx+C>0$$ we don't need $Ax^2+C>0$ and $Bx>0$ separately. $$Ax^2+Bx+C>0$$ will be held if $x>$max$(p,q)$ or $x<$min$(p,q)$ where $p,q$ are the roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee So is it somewhat like losing relationship between elements in the equation?

Comment: Are you aware of the condition mentioned in the last comment

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes...

Comment: $P+Q > 0$ is not equivalent to $P > 0$ AND $Q > 0$.  The latter is sufficient as mentioned above, but not necessary.  As $9^{x+1}+1 > 0$, we can have $(a^2-4a-2)3^x < 0$ and still the sum could be positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Suppose you rewrite $$9^{x+1}+(a^2-4a-2)\cdot3^x+1$$ as $$9 \times 9^x+(a^2-4a-2)\cdot3^x+1=9 \times 3^{2x}+(a^2-4a-2)\cdot3^x+1$$ and now define $y=3^x$. So the expression becomes $$9y^2+(a^2-4a-2)y+1$$ and you want it to be positive.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I have clearly written that I don't want a solution...I want identify my mistake... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760560/if-9x1-t2-4t-23x-1-0-then-what-values-can-t-take